# How to restrict access on only one website (with virtualhost based configuration in httpd) ? I wont to be accessible only from a specific country

Tags: web-server, router, website, restrictions, country

I wont to do it from the webserver, is it possible? Or the best practice is with access list's in the fouter, but then how other sites will be accessible from everywhere?
The operating system is "Debian 9" and the webserver is "apache2.4".

Comment: Please add the operating system and the web server type, please.

Answer (score 0):

If it is apache, you can do it with this software:

https://github.com/maxmind/mod_maxminddb